# Update Postgres table from a pg_dump dump?

Tags: postgresql, psql, pg-dump

I have 2 Postgres tables (same schema) in different servers.

One table has the the latest data, and the other one has old data that must be updated with the latest data.

So I dump the table with the latest data:

```
pg_dump --table=table00 --data-only db00 > table00.sql
```

or

```
pg_dump --table=table00 --data-only --column-inserts db00 > table00.sql
```

But now when I want to read in the SQL dump, I get errors about duplicate keys.

```
psql postgresql://<username>:<password>@localhost:5432/db00 --file=table00.sql
```

The error goes away if I drop the table with the old data first, but not only is this undesirable, it is plain silly.

How can I update a Postgres table from a SQL dump then?

Eg. it'd be nice if `pg_dump` had a `--column-updates` option, where, instead of `INSERT` statements, you got `INSERT  ON CONFLICT (column)  DO UPDATE SET` statements...

Comment: `pg_dump` only has a `--on-conflict-do-nothing` option, but not a `--on-conflict-do-update` option